# Ubuntu apt -f install equivalent in fedora

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum, dependencies

In Ubuntu I often use the command `apt -f install` to fix missing dependencies. Is there any such command in Fedora?

Also is there any equivalent of the command `gdebi` which also automatically fixes missing dependencies during install?

I am experienced in Ubuntu and now want to make hands dirty at fedora.

Comment: About `apt -f install`  http://askubuntu.com/questions/58378/what-exactly-does-sudo-apt-get-f-install-do    -f, --fix-broken

Comment: My `apt` doesn't have an `-f` option in the man page. Perhaps you're looking for the `apt-get -f | --fix-broken`

Comment: apt and apt-get ar sme in ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4):

You can find equivalences between package management commands on major Linux distributions (Arch Linux, RHEL/CentOS/Fedora, Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/elementary/…, SUSE, Gentoo) on the [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta). If you need Yum equivalents (for older RHEL/CentOS), check [DNF vs Yum](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli_vs_yum.html).

The equivalent of `apt -f -s install` as in “find missing dependencies of requested packages” is `dnf repoquery --unsatisfied`. For Yum, that's `yum check`. That tells you what to install with `dnf install`.

I don't know if Fedora has something closer to `apt-get -f install` that first tries to complete the installation of partially-installed packages.

Comment: `dnf` is not available in older fedora versions. Is there a `yum` equivalent? That said if on a newer release of fedora, there is no reason to prefer `yum` to `dnf` :)

Comment: In fedora if there is missing dependencies then how do they fix it?

Comment: Also in Ubuntu you can do it by `dpkg -i *.deb` followed by `apt -f install`, but I rather prefer `gdebi *deb`. Is there any such command like `gdebi` in fedora

Answer (score 1):

The dnf manual http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora21/man8/dnf.8.html

Yum / dnf http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli_vs_yum.html

» The gdebi functionality « : Installing downloaded packages, and their dependencies :

```
cd Downloads/
# dnf install ./[package].rpm
```

Comment: I know it, please read my question properly its not about installation, :)